# Interpolating when there's NA's

Tags: r, missing-data

I have longitudinal data structured (in **R**) as so:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(county = c("a","a","a", "b","b","b", "c","c","c"), year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003), count = c(2, NA, 6, 4, NA, 8, 10, NA, 14))
```

I have a missing year I'd like to interpolate ***2002***. Which I made a function to do:

```
dat1[dat1$year == 2002,] <- apply(X = data.frame("2001" = dat1[dat1$year == 2001, "count"], "2003" = dat1[dat1$year == 2003, "count"]), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){z <- data.frame(approx(x = x, method = "linear", n = length(2001:2003))$y); return(z[-c(1, nrow(z)),])})
dat1 # the desired result
```

But it only works when there isn't any `NA`'s in the two years that I use to interpolate:

```
dat2 <- dat1
dat2[9,3] <- NA

apply(X = data.frame("2001" = dat2[dat2$year == 2001, "count"], "2003" = dat2[dat2$year == 2003, "count"]), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){z <- data.frame(approx(x = x, method = "linear", n = length(2001:2003))$y); return(z[-c(1, nrow(z)),])})
```

I'm aware that I could just use `complete.cases()` to make it run but then I can't insert it back into the original data frame because the row lengths would differ.

Does anyone have a solution to my `NA`'s in the preceding or following years problem or better solution to my kludge-tastic attempt?

Comment: @RichardScriven, Thanks for the suggestion, I've included the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return NA if there are only NAs, replace every NA with the single non-NA using `na.aggregate` if there is only one non-NA and use `na.approx` if there is more than one NA in a county.

```
library(zoo)

na_approx <- function(x) {
    if (all(is.na(x))) NA 
    else if (sum(!is.na(x)) == 1) na.aggregate(x)
    else na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE)
}
transform(dat2, count = ave(count, county, FUN = na_approx))
```

giving:

```
  county year count
1      a 2001     2
2      a 2002     4
3      a 2003     6
4      b 2001     4
5      b 2002     6
6      b 2003     8
7      c 2001    10
8      c 2002    10
9      c 2003    10
```

Here is an alternative that can have slightly different behavior although in this example it gives the same result.

```
na_approx2 <- function(x) {
     if (sum(!is.na(x)) > 1) na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE) 
     else na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)
}
transform(dat2, count = ave(count, county, FUN = na_approx2))
```

Comment: I noticed that the `count` value for `county` _c_ in `year` 2003 is 10 when it should be `NA` for dat2.

Comment: If there is one non-NA in a county then all NAs get replaced with it.  If you want something different then replace na.aggregate(...) with whatever you want.  For example, you could use `na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)` if you only want NAs following the non-NA to be filled in.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind could you explain for me why when I tried to put your `if(cond) {exp1} else {exp2}` into a `ifelse(test = cond, yes = exp1, no = exp2)` it didn't work i.e. `ifelse(test = sum(!is.na(x)) > 1, yes = na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE), no = na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)`

Comment: if...else is not vectorized but ifelse is.

Comment: If I was missing 2001 instead of 2002, how could I use this function to **extrapolate** using the 2002 and 2003 data? Thank you for the extra help.

Comment: Use `na.approx(x, rule = 2)` . See `?approx` (which `na.approx` calls) for the definition of the `rule` argument.